# How can i retrieve the time step size for real value in the Modelica?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'm wondering how i get the each time step size for the real values to use this to the equation.
I was trying to find the functions or something else but i couldn't.

Actually, I'm trying to integrate the pressure by the volume but the integrator in the Modelica only support the time integral. So i decided to multiply the (delta_volume/delta_time) to the integral of the pressure. That's why i'm doing this.

The pseudo code is like the below.

```
  Work=Integral(pressure);
```

[image]

But integrating the pressure by the volume is what i want, not by the time. So it should be changed like this

```
  Work=(Integral(pressure)) * (delta Volume/delta time);
```

I'm not able to use the constant value for the delta time because solver cannot handle my model for fixed time step.

Please reply this to me how i can get the value of each time step size for the real value.

Comment: Can you rewrite it to use the `der()` operator instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to integrate `p dt` but `p dV=p dV/dt dt` then you have to multiply `p` by `der(V)`, there are blocks for multiplication `Modelica.Blocks.Math.Product` and differentiation `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Der`; alternatively use `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Derivative` for an approximate derivative.

Note that Dymola automatically checks units, in this case it is checked that the integral `p*der(V)` is compatible with work (i.e. "J") - which it should be.

Comment: Wow, it was a simple math and problem solved. I was so stupid.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but couldn't you compute power by

```
Power = pressure * volumeFlowRate = pressure * der(volume);
```

and then compute

```
der(Work) = Power;
```

Besides this, regarding your actual question: It is not possible to retrieve the step-size of a solver from the Modelica-code of a model.

Comment: Yes. It was a simple math haha... Thank you very much!